# Can we use library function without calling 'this'?

Tags: vue.js

If I import lodash in 'main.js', how do I call *.size(x) but not this.*.size() in one of my component?

someone said I should import lodash in my component but I would like a way to do it across all components. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try

```
window._ = require('lodash')
```

or

```
import lodash from 'lodash'
window._ = lodash
```